# Group timestamp by hour SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I am trying to group my timestamp column which has a data type of TimeStamp by hour.

So this works for grouping by day:

```
SELECT * FROM INFO
GROUP BY
DATE(timestamp)
```

I have tried the following for grouping by hour:

```
SELECT * FROM INFO
GROUP BY
HOUR(timestamp)
```

But this gives me the error:    no such function: HOUR:

I have seen similar questions asked, but it was DateTime used, not TimeStamp.

Additionally I would like to know how to group by any time period e.g by 24 hr, by 48 hr, by week, etc..

Comment: There is a methdo `strftime` in sqlite. there isn't any
 `Aggregate function` why did you need `group by`, Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Columns are Name, Posts, TimeStamp. Data is collected every 30 minutes. Meaning posts and time stamp are updated. I need to collect post avg across the rows that are grouped (by date/hour etc). So if I group by hour, I will get the average post number for that hour

Comment: TimeStamp col: 2018-07-19 10:47:06

Comment: Could your add some data and expect result  in your question(format data instead of images)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a method [strftime](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) in SQLite, Generally group by will work with an Aggregate function like (count, sum, avg ...).

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Id INT,
  `timestamp` timestamp
);

insert into t values (1,'2018-01-01 01:01:12');
insert into t values (2,'2018-01-01 02:02:12');
insert into t values (3,'2018-01-01 01:01:12');
```

Here is a sample for `strftime` method.

**Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(Id),strftime ('%H',timestamp) hour
FROM T
GROUP BY strftime ('%H',timestamp)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fgPRaWfoHgLMPSxWKqck6f/0)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Although how do I edit this to capture every 2 hour etc

Comment: @fints1col yes, you can make a calendar by **CTE Recursion** then `left join` it  here is a sample http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/453d6/19

Comment: ('%H',timestamp) hour, is there a way to change this to %D? . In order to do the same thing, but by Day, rather than hour?

Comment: The sqlfiddle has is no longer working, could you provide it again please?

Comment: could be `group by hour` as "hour" is cleverly defined as an alias. juste more elegant.